# CRON is failing

Tags: server

My CRON jobs are not running. Getting following error in syslog file

```
(root) CMD (curl localhost -m 20 --connect-timeout 10 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/local/sbin/apacherestart)
```

Please assist me on this. I am new to ubuntu.

Thanks,
Tejashri Pandit

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure notices from syslog are related to your question. That line you show is NOT related to cron but to a command (CMD) starting apache. Lines in logs related to cron are marked with CRON. Not CMD.

In regards to your log entry: please take good care of spaces. You are missing one. See the command you issued and that got logged: `/usr/local/sbin/apacherestart`.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind for your comments. I am getting this log when I tried to fetch logs which are related with CRON with command "grep CRON syslog" and it shows log as "Feb  7 11:00:01 s2410 CRON[23012]: (root) CMD (curl localhost -m 20 --connect-timeout 10 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/local/sbin/apacherestart)
"

Comment: so add a space to the command as I explained. `/usr/local/sbin/apacherestart` is not a valid method.

Comment: @Rinzwind AFAIK log lines related to cron contain both `CRON` and `CMD` - the assertion that the OP's issue is not related to cron seems unhelpful

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on logs.. We found the root cause of CRON failure .. it was due to SSL certificate.

Comment: I hope you will create and Answer here which explains how you found that solution.